# Add data-title from headline to every td with Javascript (for loop in two dimensional array)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

I've got an html table where I want to add the cell content from the headline as data-title to every td for responsive html tables.

The problem is, when I want to set the attribute for the tbody cells, that I got the message:

> "array[i] is undefined".

My Javascript Code looks like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var head = document.querySelector("table > thead");
    var body = document.querySelector("table > tbody");

    var columncount = body.rows[0].cells.length;
    var headItems = head.rows[0].cells;

    var headRows = head.rows;
    var headCells = [];
    var array = []

    if (headItems.length == columncount) {

        for (var i = 0; i < headRows.length; i++) {
            var columns = [];
            headCells = headRows[i].cells;

            for (var m = 0; m < headCells.length; m++) {
                columns[m] = headCells[m].innerHTML;
            }
            array[i] = columns;
        }
    }
    var bodyRows = body.rows;

    for (j = 0; j < bodyRows.length; j++) {
        var bodyCells = bodyRows[j].cells;
        for (k = 0; k < bodyCells.length; k++) {
            bodyCells[k].setAttribute("data-title", array[i][m]); // NOTE array[i][m] here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to view what is the content of `array[i]` by console.log it

Comment: console.log: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: `console.log(array)` is undefined?

Answer (score 3):

If you use jQuery in your project this could help:

```
// Add data-title to every <td>
$( "table" ).each( function( index, tableID ) {
    $( tableID ).find( "thead tr th" ).each( function( index ) {
        index += 1;
        $( tableID ).find( "tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")" ).attr( "data-title", $(this).text() );
    });
});
```

Works only for tables which have `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags inside.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you choose a variable, don't use a javascript keyword name, for example, instead of using `array`, use `_array` or `arr` or other variables.

I think you need to add a content to this `array`. Try to add something to your `array`, because if you do `array[i]`, `array` is empty and don't have `i` index.

Try this:

```
_array.push(some_value);
```

Then, you can do this `_array[0]` for instance.