# What does ** (double asterisk) mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I was reviewing a suggested edit for [a JavaScript question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484896/add-data-title-from-headline-to-every-td-with-javascript-for-loop-in-two-dimens) and there were many changes suggested, but what caught my eye was the suggestion to change the following line:

```
bodyCells[k].setAttribute("data-title", **array[i][m]**);
```

To this:

```
bodyCells[k].setAttribute("data-title", * * array[i][m] * * );
```

To me, both `**` and `* *` don't look quite right in this context. Are either or both correct? If so, what is the meaning?

From searching online, it seems that unlike some languages, in JavaScript `**` is NOT used for exponents. In fact, [Math.pow() seems to be the function of choice for exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907063/javascript-exponents). So it seems to have nothing to do with that.

UPDATE:

As of ECMAScript 2016, `**` is now used in JavaScript for exponentiation. Thanks to Tomas Nikodym for pointing that out!

Comment: My guess is OP tried to use bold style

Comment: **bold style**, here, not sure in javascript. Don't think it works though.. And your console probably agrees.

Comment: I think the question is off-topic

Comment: Based on comments, comment upvotes, and the answer below, at least nine people believe that this is an erroneous attempt to use Markdown to emphasize `array[i][m]` in that line of code. I edited that question to remove those asterisks. Thanks everyone!

Comment: The title of the question is rather misleading. Note that `**` is a valid JavaScript operator since ECMAScript 2016 (it's the [exponentiation operator](https://github.com/rwaldron/exponentiation-operator)).

Comment: @TomasNikodym Thanks for letting me know. Note added to post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those would both be syntax errors. It is perhaps an attempt to use Markdown style for bold text (i.e. `**text**` becomes **text**). StackOverflow uses Markdown in questions, answers, and comments. It is completely unrelated to JavaScript.

However, in this case, the action seems to be intended to make that text bold.

[Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)

Comment: Why did this receive a downvote? Alternative answers would be very much appreciated, if this answer is not correct.